# Do Apple push notification service (APNS) p8/p12 certificates expire?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I currently use APNS *.p8 key file and my question is about it's expiration time. I do not use *.p12 but anyone else may be interested in them also. How often should I generate new *.p8/*.p12 files?